# How can we set the certificates correctly while calling a secured service from Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to connect to an SSL web service via a Spring Boot RestTemplate and am running my code via IntelliJ + Gradle. I have downloaded the certificates of the destination web service and added them to a keystore as shown

`keytool -import -file pub_cert.pem -alias event-broker -keystore cacerts`

Then the keystore has been added via a JVM command parameter

`applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\\Temp", "-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\\tmp\\cacerts"]`

However when I am still trying to access the service, I get the error

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_required`

I have created my RestTemplate as follows: Is there anything that you can suggest?

```
RestTemplate restTemplate() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {
    SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
            .loadTrustMaterial((chain, authType) -> true)
            .build();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
            .build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory =
            new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    return new RestTemplate(factory);
}
```

Thanks,
Prabal

Comment: Can you please add the JVM argument Djavax.net.debug=all and capture the logs. Those logs might help us understand the root cause , more details can be found below : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html